# Sqoop not working with Oozie (using HUE)

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, sqoop, oozie, hue

I tried to use sqoop using Oozie scheduler, however the job is killed immediately by Oozie. Sqoop command works fine through terminal.

```
sqoop import \
    --connect  "jdbc:xxxxxxxx" \
    --username=xxxxxxxx \
    --password=xxxxxxxx \
    --driver ctree.jdbc.ctreeDriver \
    --table odhfgdb  \
    --target-dir "/acting/user/odhfgdb-tmp" \
    --fields-terminated-by '\001'  \
    --escaped-by \\  \
    --delete-target-dir \
    --split-by entry_date \
    --where="entry_date < CURRENT_DATE" --m 30
```

Can you tell me, what do I need to do in Oozie for this command to work?

Following is the log:

```
2016-06-27 19:27:51,492  INFO ActionStartXCommand:543 - SERVER[servername] USER[admin] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[My_Workflow] JOB[0000010-160627000427464-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000010-160627000427464-oozie-oozi-W@:start:] Start action [0000010-160627000427464-oozie-oozi-W@:start:] with user-retry state : userRetryCount [0], userRetryMax [0], userRetryInterval [10]
2016-06-27 19:27:51,493  INFO ActionStartXCommand:543 - SERVER[servername] USER[admin] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[My_Workflow] JOB[0000010-160627000427464-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000010-160627000427464-oozie-oozi-W@:start:] [***0000010-160627000427464-oozie-oozi-W@:start:***]Action status=DONE
2016-06-27 19:27:51,494  INFO ActionStartXCommand:543 - SERVER[servername] USER[admin] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[My_Workflow] JOB[0000010-160627000427464-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000010-160627000427464-oozie-oozi-W@:start:] [***0000010-160627000427464-oozie-oozi-W@:start:***]Action updated in DB!
2016-06-27 19:27:52,310  INFO ActionStartXCommand:543 - SERVER[servername] USER[admin] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[My_Workflow] JOB[0000010-160627000427464-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000010-160627000427464-oozie-oozi-W@sqoop-283e] Start action [0000010-160627000427464-oozie-oozi-W@sqoop-283e] with user-retry state : userRetryCount [0], userRetryMax [0], userRetryInterval [10]
2016-06-27 19:27:56,418  INFO SqoopActionExecutor:543 - SERVER[servername] USER[admin] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[My_Workflow] JOB[0000010-160627000427464-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000010-160627000427464-oozie-oozi-W@sqoop-283e] checking action, hadoop job ID [job_1466989378023_0024] status [RUNNING]
2016-06-27 19:27:56,420  INFO ActionStartXCommand:543 - SERVER[servername] USER[admin] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[My_Workflow] JOB[0000010-160627000427464-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000010-160627000427464-oozie-oozi-W@sqoop-283e] [***0000010-160627000427464-oozie-oozi-W@sqoop-283e***]Action status=RUNNING
2016-06-27 19:27:56,421  INFO ActionStartXCommand:543 - SERVER[servername] USER[admin] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[My_Workflow] JOB[0000010-160627000427464-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000010-160627000427464-oozie-oozi-W@sqoop-283e] [***0000010-160627000427464-oozie-oozi-W@sqoop-283e***]Action updated in DB!
2016-06-27 19:28:14,293  INFO CallbackServlet:543 - SERVER[servername] USER[-] GROUP[-] TOKEN[-] APP[-] JOB[0000010-160627000427464-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000010-160627000427464-oozie-oozi-W@sqoop-283e] callback for action [0000010-160627000427464-oozie-oozi-W@sqoop-283e]
2016-06-27 19:28:15,752  INFO SqoopActionExecutor:543 - SERVER[servername] USER[admin] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[My_Workflow] JOB[0000010-160627000427464-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000010-160627000427464-oozie-oozi-W@sqoop-283e] action completed, external ID [job_1466989378023_0024]
2016-06-27 19:28:15,764  WARN SqoopActionExecutor:546 - SERVER[servername] USER[admin] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[My_Workflow] JOB[0000010-160627000427464-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000010-160627000427464-oozie-oozi-W@sqoop-283e] Launcher ERROR, reason: Main class [org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.SqoopMain], exit code [1]
2016-06-27 19:28:16,137  INFO ActionEndXCommand:543 - SERVER[servername] USER[admin] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[My_Workflow] JOB[0000010-160627000427464-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000010-160627000427464-oozie-oozi-W@sqoop-283e] ERROR is considered as FAILED for SLA
2016-06-27 19:28:16,257  INFO ActionStartXCommand:543 - SERVER[servername] USER[admin] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[My_Workflow] JOB[0000010-160627000427464-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000010-160627000427464-oozie-oozi-W@Kill] Start action [0000010-160627000427464-oozie-oozi-W@Kill] with user-retry state : userRetryCount [0], userRetryMax [0], userRetryInterval [10]
2016-06-27 19:28:16,258  INFO ActionStartXCommand:543 - SERVER[servername] USER[admin] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[My_Workflow] JOB[0000010-160627000427464-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000010-160627000427464-oozie-oozi-W@Kill] [***0000010-160627000427464-oozie-oozi-W@Kill***]Action status=DONE
2016-06-27 19:28:16,259  INFO ActionStartXCommand:543 - SERVER[servername] USER[admin] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[My_Workflow] JOB[0000010-160627000427464-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000010-160627000427464-oozie-oozi-W@Kill] [***0000010-160627000427464-oozie-oozi-W@Kill***]Action updated in DB!
```

Following is the workflow generated in HUE:

```
<workflow-app name="My_Workflow" xmlns="uri:oozie:workflow:0.5">
    <start to="sqoop-283e"/>
    <kill name="Kill">
        <message>Action failed, error message[${wf:errorMessage(wf:lastErrorNode())}]</message>
    </kill>
    <action name="sqoop-283e">
        <sqoop xmlns="uri:oozie:sqoop-action:0.2">
            <job-tracker>${jobTracker}</job-tracker>
            <name-node>${nameNode}</name-node>
            <command>import  --connect jdbc:xxxxxxx --username=xxxxxx --password=xxxxxxx --driver ctree.jdbc.ctreeDriver --table odhfgdb --target-dir /acting/user/odhfgdb-tmp --fields-terminated-by \001 --escaped-by \\ --delete-target-dir --split-by entry_date --where=entry_date &lt; CURRENT_DATE --m 30</command>
        </sqoop>
        <ok to="End"/>
        <error to="Kill"/>
    </action>
    <end name="End"/>
</workflow-app>
```

Comment: Are you using the `<command>` tag in oozie sqoop action, while running through the oozie. You should use the `<arg>` list for passing all the parameter/options. Because `<command>` tag is split by whitespace and I see the `--where="entry_date < CURRENT_DATE"` contains whitespace. If this does not solve the issue, please provide the logs from launcher job.

Comment: Post your workflow with actions...

Comment: @YoungHobbit : I have posted logs, however I will try using arg now

Comment: @TKHN : I have posted it

Comment: You have posted the logs from oozie server, you need to check the launcher mapper logs. There you will find the issue.